# List-group toogle com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tentei e não consegui. Tenho uma `list` do *Bootstrap* e preciso fazer com que ao clicar no item `.active`, os demais abaixo abram com o `.toggle()`, mas não sei fazer, está se comportando bem estranho.

```
<html>
<style>
    .list-widget .list-group-item { display: none; }
    .list-widget .list-group-item:active { display: block; }
</style>
<div class="list-group list-widget">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Lista#01</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#01</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#02</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#03</a>
</div>
<div class="list-group list-widget">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Lista#02</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#01</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#02</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#03</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list-widget .list-group-item.active').click(function(){
        // Aqui abrir e fechar com .toggle();
        // Somente as .list-group-item da lista relacionada
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu CSS tem um erro em `:active`, onde deveria ser `.active`. E para abrir os outros itens com `.toggle` você pode usar `.siblings()` (elementos irmãos).

É interessante ainda usar `.preventDefault()` para cancelar o evento do clique no link.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list-widget .list-group-item.active').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).siblings().toggle(400);
    });
});
```

```css
.list-widget .list-group-item { display: none; }
.list-widget .list-group-item.active { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="list-group list-widget">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Lista#01</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#01</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#02</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#03</a>
</div>
<div class="list-group list-widget">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Lista#02</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#01</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#02</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#03</a>
</div>
```

> Para ter o efeito tipo "sanfona", o `.toogle()` deve ter um valor, seja
>   numérico em milissegundos ou `"slow"` ou `"fast"`. No caso acima usei `400`, que um valor intermediário entre o `"slow"` (`600`) e mais lento que o `"fast"` (`200`).

## Usando .slideToggle()

O efeito fica bem melhor usando `.slideToggle()`. Isso porque o `.toggle()`, durante a animação, aumenta (ao mostrar) e reduz (ao esconder) a largura dos elementos.

Veja a diferença com `.slideToggle()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list-widget .list-group-item.active').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).siblings().slideToggle(400);
    });
});
```

```css
.list-widget .list-group-item{ display: none; }
.list-widget .list-group-item.active { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="list-group list-widget">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Lista#01</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#01</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#02</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#03</a>
</div>
<div class="list-group list-widget">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Lista#02</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#01</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#02</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#03</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, o efeito agradou bastante também !!!! =D

Answer (score 2):

Criei um uma `div` com a classe "sub-itens", deixo ela oculta utilizando o método `hide`, até que o clique na `div` com a classe "active" faça o `toggle` no próximo elemento que no caso é a div com a classe "sub-tens", veja o resultado abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sub-itens').hide();
    $('.list-widget .list-group-item.active').click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle("slow");
    });    
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group list-widget">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Lista#01</a>
    <div class="sub-itens">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#01</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#02</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#03</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="list-group list-widget">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Lista#02</a>
    <div class="sub-itens">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#01</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#02</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item#03</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Wictor!